# Firebase Audiences and event sequences

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, analysis, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to create an audience in Firebase for users who register with the app and then make their first parking transaction or paid reservation in a certain amount of days. I have three events in firebase for this. They are called *confirm*, *parking* and *paid_reservation*. When I first tried to make this audience I thought I should create a conditional group. Something that looks like this:[image]

As you can see I want to see the user who confirmed and then parked or registered within 4 days. This seems to work fine but then I thought what is the difference between that Audience and this Audience:

[image]

Lastly I thought this is actually a small sequence of events and I should actually click on the button add sequence and create an audience looking like this:[image]

the problem though with this last group is that on the right it says *Incomplete or invalid audience definition*. This appears when I add *or made paid reservation*. I would like to know why this doesn't work and what is the difference between all three of them?
I have done some research about audiences but you mostly find blogs only and not really explaining my particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar trouble myself, in my case, I needed to add a parameter to every row in order to get past the error.  I'm not sure if there's something similar going on for you in your third situation or not.  Is it possible that combining a sequence with a non-parameter group is requiring the group to have a parameter value?

I think that a simple way to at least test is to see the exact moment that the error appears.  Is it when you click add sequence?  When you add the first row to the sequence, but haven't added a parameter yet?  Later?

Best of luck!